# How to Update Date and Time of Raspberry Pi With out Internet

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have connect my Raspberry Pi to LAN but there is no internet available. Is there any method to update raspberry pi date time by using a PC (windows 7) in LAN? I want to get computer date and time to my Raspberry Pi when it is booting.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 54):

Remember that Raspberry Pi does not have real time clock. So even you are connected to internet have to set the time every time you power on or restart.

This is how it works:

1. Type `sudo raspi-config` in the Raspberry Pi command line
2. Internationalization options
3. Change Time Zone
4. Select geographical area
5. Select city or region
6. Reboot your pi

Next thing you can set time using this command

```
sudo date -s "Mon Aug  12 20:14:11 UTC 2014"
```

More about data and time

```
man date
```

When Pi is connected to computer should have to manually set data and time

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the replies.
What I did was,
1. I install [meinberg ntp software](http://www.satsignal.eu/ntp/setup.html) application on windows 7 pc. (softros ntp server is also possible.)
 2. change raspberry pi ntp.conf file (for auto update date and time)

```
server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx iburst
server 1.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

3. If you want to make sure that date and time update at startup run this python script in rpi,

```
import os

try:
    client = ntplib.NTPClient()
    response = client.request('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', version=4)
    print "===================================="
    print "Offset : "+str(response.offset)
    print "Version : "+str(response.version)
    print "Date Time : "+str(ctime(response.tx_time))
    print "Leap : "+str(ntplib.leap_to_text(response.leap))
    print "Root Delay : "+str(response.root_delay)
    print "Ref Id : "+str(ntplib.ref_id_to_text(response.ref_id))
    os.system("sudo date -s '"+str(ctime(response.tx_time))+"'")
    print "===================================="
except:
    os.system("sudo date")
    print "NTP Server Down Date Time NOT Set At The Startup"
    pass
```

I found [more info](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=84723) in raspberry pi forum.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to configure your Win7 PC as a Time Server, and then configure the RasPi to connect to it for NTP services.

Configure Win7 as [authoritative time server](https://support.automation.siemens.com/WW/llisapi.dll?func=cslib.csinfo&objId=22144503&load=treecontent&lang=en&siteid=cseus&aktprim=0&objaction=csview&extranet=standard&viewreg=WW).
Configure RasPi [time server lookup](http://www.ronnutter.com/raspberry-pi-ntp-client-setup/).