# Not install azure-storage command in Raspberry PI-3 terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I'm working on Raspberry PI-3. I'm trying to communicate Raspberry PI-3 to Azure storage account using Python, and try to write data into azure table. But When I install `pip install azure-storage` on terminal, I getting following error.

```
Downloading/unpacking azure-storage
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1178, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 194, in find_requirement
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_page
    session=self.session,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 694, in get_page
    req, link, "connection error: %s" % exc, url,
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type Error)

Storing debug log for failure in /home/pi/.pip/pip.log
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

**P.S:** Sorry for my poor English.

**Edit:** pip.log files log.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/bin/pip run on Sat Jun  4 04:34:00 2016
Downloading/unpacking azure-storage
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/azure-storage/
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1178, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 194, in find_requirement
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_page
    session=self.session,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 694, in get_page
    req, link, "connection error: %s" % exc, url,
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type Error)
```

Comment: Can you also share the appropriate log entries from pip.log?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes sir.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem in raspbery pi 3. I've solved this problem by setting the correct time and date.

You can set time using this command

```
sudo date -s "Tue Feb 14 20:14:11 IST  2017"
```

When Pi is connected to computer should have to manually set data and time.

Reference link : [How to Update Date and Time of Raspberry Pi With out Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374570/how-to-update-date-and-time-of-raspberry-pi-with-out-internet)